# Autocomplete Atom funções de classes incluidas

Tags: autocompletar, atom

Gostaria de saber se existe um plugin que faça o autocomplete semelhante ao do netbeans, que complete as funções de uma classe estanciada. Ex: `$agi->funcao;`

No netbeans, quando incluímos a classe no arquivo, ele já começa a autocompletar também com as funções do arquivo.

Com atom-autocomplete-php consegui um breve vislumbre dessa função. O editor sugere a função porem apenas se a classe estiver aberta e também não mostra os parâmetros da função, exemplo: `$agi->funcao($parametro);`